# How many k-subsets of the integers {1,...,n} sum to N?

Tags: co.combinatorics

Given the set of integers $S = \{1,..n\}$, how many subsets of $S$ with $k$ elements sum to $N\in \mathbb Z$?

Comment: What exactly do you mean asking "how many"? There is no closed expression, I am afraid.

Comment: Could you give a bit more background for your question? For instance, where did this question arise? Would you be happy with an asymptotic formula? etc

Answer (score 4):

See http://mathworld.wolfram.com/PartitionFunctionQ.html, or google "partitions into distinct parts"

Answer (score 2):

There is a bijection between the subsets of size $k$ summing to $N$ and partitions of $N-{k \choose 2}$ with $k$ parts so that each part has size at most $n-k+1$,

$$\lbrace a_0 \lt a_1 \lt ... \lt a_{k-1} \rbrace \leftrightarrow \sum (a_i - i),$$

or partitions of $N-{k+1 \choose 2}$ into at most $k$ parts so that each part has size at most $n-k$,

$$\sum(a_i-i-1).$$

Those are partitions of $N-{k+1 \choose 2}$ whose Ferrers diagrams fit inside a $k \times (n-k)$ box. For a fixed $k$ and $n$, the generating function is a [Gaussian binomial coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) ${n \choose k}_q$.